Cluster versus Index level allocation in Elasticsearch
(Setup) In one of our production cluster, we have four entities namely user, call, interaction and comment indexed on an Elasticsearch(5.4.1). As the scale of these entities is increasing, we are facing exceptions during our index requests such as:
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsRejectedExecutionException: 
rejected execution of org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport$RequestHandler@7ebd7280 on EsThreadPoolExecutor
[index, queue capacity = 200, org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor@de367fc[Running, pool size = 16, active threads = 16, queued tasks = 200, completed tasks = 1639629]]

(Cause)
Upon diving in further over the details, I have identified that our user index is the primary reason of concerns with the index throughput being high and its on the nodes where the primary shard for this index is present that we often see the exceptions.
As referenced under the threadpool modules guide, its not really recommended to increase the thread pool for the operation.

(Attempt)
Now, what I am tying is to follow the index based shard allocation and ensure that there are dedicated nodes allocated to the user index and the rest of the nodes can be used for the other indices. I am planning to execute the following settings update:
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
      "cluster.routing.allocation.include.rack": "compute,storage",
      "cluster.routing.allocation.include.size": "big,small"
  }
}

PUT user/_settings
{
  "index.routing.allocation.include.rack": "compute",
  "index.routing.allocation.include.size": "big"
}

(Doubt)
Given the above configuration,
Q1. Would it ensure that no other indices such as call, comment etc hold their primary shards on the nodes labelled compute and big?
Q2. If a new node is created without any label such as rack and size, would allocation of any indices not happen on those nodes?
